# Not able to open link with default browser in Safari / iOS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, canvas

i have a canvas application renders inside iframe salesforce lightening.

in that i render an html page where i present few external links to user. when user clicks on any external link, i want it to open with default browser. it is working in every browser other than safari and salesforce mobile app(it internally uses safari).

But in iOS it is not opening default browser. is there any setting i need to enable?

tried presenting links as 
1) anchor tag with href
2) window.open(url)
3) generate anchor tag programmatically and triggering click event on it

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
               link.href = payload.url;
               link.target = "_system";
               link.click();
```

nothing is working. can someone suggest how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are using the correct value(target="_system"), [it's not supported directly from HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

As a workaround try to do the same from Js using window.open function, I found this workaround over [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-opening-links-in-content-in-system-browser-instead-of-cordova-browser-wrapper/2427)

Example: `window.open(payload.url, '_system', 'location=yes');`

Comment: it is working in safari browser. not in salesforce1 mobile app quick action view. any idea?

Comment: Technically it should work, have you tried clearing the cache(maybe force stop the app and try again).

Comment: technically it should. unfortunately it is not.

Comment: refer: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AarGIAS
not sure if salesforce itself will not allow